# In Java, is there a way to obtain the component where an event is being handled?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, event-handling

Suppose I have 4 squares colored blue, white, red and green (myComponent) associated with the mouse press event. At one point, the mouse is pressed over one of them - say, the yellow one - and the event is activated.

Now, the control flux is inside the event handling function. How do I get the MyComponent - the yellow square - that caused this from here?

EDIT

I have another question. Is there a way to tell the position of the component? My problem is a bit more complicated than what I said.

Basically, I have a grid full of squares. When I click one of the squares, I have to know which one it is, so I can update my matrix. The thing is, if I calculate it myself, it only works on a given resolution.

I have a GridBagLayout, and inside it are the myComponents. I have to know which one of the components exactly - like, component[2][2] - caused the interruption.

I mean, I can tell which one of the components did it, but not where in the matrix it is located.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`MouseEvent.getSource()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource()) returns the object on which the event initially occurred.

> I have a `GridBagLayout`, and inside it
>   are the `myComponents`. I have to know
>   which one of the components exactly -
>   like, `component[2][2]` - caused the
>   interruption.

You could store the indices, e.g. `(2,2)`, inside each `myComponent` when you add them to the matrix. That way, given the component, you can always identify its position in the matrix.

```
class MyComponent extends JButton
{
    final int i; // matrix row
    final int j; // matrix col

    // constructor
    MyComponent(String text, int i, int j)
    {
        super(text);
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By adding a [`MouseListener`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) (or alternatively, a [`MouseAdapter`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html), if you don't need to override all the `MouseListener' methods) to each of your colored boxes, when an event such as a mouse click occurs, the`MouseListener`will be called with a [`MouseEvent`][3](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html), which can be used to obtain the component that was clicked.

For example:

```
final MyBoxComponent blueBox =   // ... Initialize blue box
final MyBoxComponent whiteBox =  // ... Initialize white box
final MyBoxComponent redBox =    // ... Initialize red box
final MyBoxComponent greenBox =  // ... Initialize green box

MouseListener myListener = new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        // Obtain the Object which caused the event.
        Object source = e.getSource();

        if (source == blueBox)
        {
            System.out.println("Blue box clicked");
        }
        else if (source == whiteBox)
        {
            System.out.println("White box clicked");
        }
        // ... and so on.
    }
};

blueBox.addMouseListener(myListener);
whiteBox.addMouseListener(myListener);
redBox.addMouseListener(myListener);
greenBox.addMouseListener(myListener);
```